# deepin-terminal: The drop-down menu does not disappear when I click with the left mouse button

Tags: ubuntu-20.04

In the deepin terminal the drop-down menu appears when I click with the right mouse button but it does not disappear when I click with the left mouse button but only by pressing the "Esc" key, why?
I'm using Ubuntu Desktop 20.04.3 LTS 64-bit.
If I use Deepin desktop instead of other desktop environments (Gnome Desktop, Cinnamon), the problem doesn't arise.
How to solve the problem regardless of the Desktop environment used?

[image]

Comment: This seems to be a bug with the Deepin project. Have you checked reported bugs or reported?

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 20.04 repo has the deprecated GTK version of deepin terminal.This issue was actually fixed by this [commit](https://github.com/martyr-deepin/deepin-terminal-gtk/commit/1d3a33937f8f49d654f654a8fe16e0380c0d36c4), but it is not present in the build we get from the repo I assume.

To fix this, either you can upgrade to Ubuntu 22.04, which has the Qt/DTK version of Deepin terminal (which is currently maintained) or you can clone the latest version of [GTK Terminal](https://github.com/martyr-deepin/deepin-terminal-gtk) from Github and build it. After building you would need to set the `prefer_deepin_menu` option to `false` in
`~/.config/deepin/deepin-terminal-gtk/config.conf`

You can find the build instructions in the [readme](https://github.com/martyr-deepin/deepin-terminal-gtk/blob/master/README.md) and you can also refer to this [Github issue](https://github.com/linuxdeepin/developer-center/issues/3278)